# Condição para chamar mascará!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Como posso fazer para ler o primeiro caractere digitado no input e a parte da condição ser chamado uma mascara especifica.

```js
if(Se o primeiro caractere no input for letra){



}else{

$('#login_username').mask('(99) 9999-9999?9').focusout(function() {
         var phone, element;
         element = $(this);
         element.unmask();
         phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
         if( phone.substring(0, 1) === '0' ) {
             element.mask("9999-999-9999");
         } else if (phone.length > 10) {
             element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
         } else {
             element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
         }
     }).trigger('focusout');
}
```

Comment: Troque a imagem pelo código pf @IgorSiqueira

Comment: Pronto! Feito!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar regex com o script [xregexp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp).

Aí é só dar um match com a expressão `\p{L}`. Se retornar, é true, e passa na condição.

**-- Editado**

Tente isso:

```
if (!isNaN(str.charAt(0))) // * charAt(0) é a primeiro char. verifica se ele não é um "Not-a-Number" - ou seja, um caractere válido para você.
```

Comment: Entao tem que ser somente com Jquery ou JavaScript.

Comment: Isto é JavaScript.